# Algorithm for finding weight of path with lowest weight in weighted directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

I am given a G=(V,E) directed graph, and all of its edges have weight of either "0" or "1".

I'm given a vertex named "A" in the graph, and for each v in V, i need to find the weight of the path from A to v which has the lowest weight in time O(V+E). 
I have to use only BFS or DFS (although this is probably a BFS problem).

I though about making a new graph where vertices that have an edge of 0 between them are united and then run BFS on it, but that would ruin the graph direction (this would work if the graph was undirected or the weights were {2,1} and for an edge of 2 i would create a new vertex).

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be done with a combination of DFS and BFS.

In the original BFS for an unweighted graph, we have the invariant that the distance of nodes unexplored have a greater or equal distance to those nodes explored.

In our BFS, for each node we first do DFS through all 0 weighted edges, mark down the distance, and mark it as explored. Then we can continue the other nodes in our BFS.

```
Array Seen[] = false
Empty queue Q
E' = {(a, b) | (a, b) = 0 and (a, b) is of E}

DFS(V, E', u)
    for each v is adjacent to u in E' // (u, v) has an edge weighted 0
        if Seen[v] = false
            v.dist = u.dist
            DFS(V, E', v)
    Seen[u] = true
    Enqueue(Q, u)

BFS(V, E, source)
    Enqueue(Q, source)
    source.dist = 0
    DFS(V, E', source)
    while (Q is not empty)
        u = Dequeue(Q)
        for each v is adjacent to u in E
            if Seen[v] = false
                v.dist = u.dist + 1
                Enqueue(Q, v)
        Seen[u] = true
```

After running the BFS, it can give you all shortest distance from the node source. If you only want a shortest distance to a single node, simply terminate when you see the destination node. And yes, it meets the requirement of O(V+E) time complexity.

Comment: Thank you for the elaborate response, however what i need is the weight of the shortest path. Where can I find that in this answer?  will the "dist" paramater of vertices here will actually be the weight?

Comment: @AtsrA That `dist` gives the sum of weights of all the edges along the path. I hope that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be modified to the problem of **Single Source Shortest Path**.

You just need to reverse all the edge directions and find the minimum distance of each vertex v from the vertex A.

It could be easily observed that if in the initial graph if we had a minimal path from some vertex v to A, after changing the edge directions we would have the same minimal path from A to v.

This could be simply done either by [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Directed_graphs_with_nonnegative_weights) OR as the edges just have two values {0 and 1}, it could also be done by modified BFS (first go to vertexes with distance 0, then 1, then 2 and so on.).

Comment: I need the weight of the lightest weight path, and not the distance of the minimal path. in theory i could have a graph with the vertex A and another v, that has a path between them of 1 edge with weight "1", and another path with 100 edges all weight "0" so the algorithm should actually find the 100 edges path as it is lighter. Can you elaborate how what you suggested finds the weight (and also how it is an O(V+E)? as Dijkstra is worse than that.